# TypeError: func(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner of JavaScript. I am trying to understand the functions and promises in JS. I wrote a small code. 
code Purpose: I wrote this code to understand the working of promise function(`then`) on function with a return value.
      input: a,b
      output: if the sum of a & b is 0, then show the alert statement else show sum in the alert value.

```js
const func = (a, b) => {

  let operand1 = a * 10;
  let operand2 = b * 10;

  return operand1 + operand2
};

const funcwrapper = (a, b) => {
  func(a, b).then((sum) => {
    if (sum == 0) {
      window.alert("value is zero");
    } else {
      window.alert(("sum is " + sum));
    }
  })
};

funcwrapper(5, 5);
```

I am still confused with this promise on functions with some return value after going through lot of investigation. So finally tried to implement the code to understand and got stuck with this error.

Please help me in understanding this topic.

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `func(a, b)` returns a number, not a promise.

Comment: `func()` needs to return a promise that resolves to the sum, not return the sum directly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Can i convert this func into a promise? and work with the return value in then?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it with the same example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`func()` needs to return a promise:

```js
const func = (a, b) => {

  let operand1 = a * 10;
  let operand2 = b * 10;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(operand1 + operand2));
};

const funcwrapper = (a, b) => {
  func(a, b).then((sum) => {
    if (sum == 0) {
      window.alert("value is zero");
    } else {
      window.alert(("sum is " + sum));
    }
  })
};

funcwrapper(5, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on it. Is there any we could find whether the return of an inbuilt function is a promise or not? For example, Parsing a text file returns a promise like that.

Comment: You need to read the documentation of the function. They all say what they return.

Comment: In general, only async functions return promises. And only recent ones, since promises are a relatively new feature of the language. Before that, async functions took a callback argument.

Comment: these clarifications help me in better understanding of the language.